# Серийный for для пользовательского класса

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Читал учебник и возник такой вопрос: можно ли как-нибудь заставить серийный оператор for работать с пользовательскими классами? Допустим, имеется класс

```
class MyContainer {
public:
    MyContainer();
    ~MyContainer();
    int& operator [] (unsigned int index);
private:
    int Arr[10];
};
```

Хочется иметь возможность обработать объект этого класса следующим образом:

```
for (int& num : myContainer) {
    //some code
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Просто напишите `begin()` и `end()` для вашего контейнера

```
class MyContainer {
  ...
  auto begin() { return std::begin(Arr); }
  auto end() { return std::end(Arr); }
  ...
};
```

Ну и константные версии, как водится...